# Overflow: Auto elements not scrolling properly in vertically centered element

Tags: html, css

When adding `overflow:auto` to my vertically centered "Menu Items" and reducing the screen height the top "Menu Items" are not scrolling all the way to the top. See fiddle and image bellow.

[image]

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y5ztd6oa/3/)

Any ideas to make the element vertically scroll properly while still being vertically centered. Preferably in CSS only if possible.

```css
.menu {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

.menu-items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.first-item {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-items">
    <ul>
      <li class="first-item">Menu Item 1</li>
      <li>Menu Item 2</li>
      <li>Menu Item 3</li>
      <li>Menu Item 4</li>
      <li>Menu Item 5</li>
      <li>Menu Item 6</li>
      <li>Menu Item 7</li>
      <li>Menu Item 8</li>
      <li>Menu Item 9</li>
      <li>Menu Item 10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .menu-items should have `min-height` not `height`

```css
.menu {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

.menu-items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
}

li {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.first-item {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-items">
    <ul>
      <li class="first-item">Menu Item 1</li>
      <li>Menu Item 2</li>
      <li>Menu Item 3</li>
      <li>Menu Item 4</li>
      <li>Menu Item 5</li>
      <li>Menu Item 6</li>
      <li>Menu Item 7</li>
      <li>Menu Item 8</li>
      <li>Menu Item 9</li>
      <li>Menu Item 10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Great job! This works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you were going for means this change:

Change the CSS rule for `.menu-items` to this:

```
.menu-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No, I want the menu items to be vertically centered not horizontally centered. The issue is when i vertically center the elements and reduce the height my menu items start getting cut off in the scroll box (refer to image above).

Comment: No worries. Still not vertically aligned centered when adjusting the height.

Answer (score 0):

Removing *position: fixed;*  solves the problem

Comment: The element needs to be position fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i checked over your code but it looks like nothing is wrong. I think it is a resolution problem(the jsFiddle compiler is only the resolution of half a page and the stack overflow snippet compiler is only like 1/20 of a page). Here I have revised your code by adding a br element. Try running the code below in fullscreen mode.

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-items">
   <br>
    <ul>
      <li class="first-item">Menu Item 1</li>
      <li>Menu Item 2</li>
      <li>Menu Item 3</li>
      <li>Menu Item 4</li>
      <li>Menu Item 5</li>
      <li>Menu Item 6</li>
      <li>Menu Item 7</li>
      <li>Menu Item 8</li>
      <li>Menu Item 9</li>
      <li>Menu Item 10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .menu {
      background: red;
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%;
      position: fixed;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .menu-items {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    li {
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .first-item {
      background: blue;
    }
    
    <div class="menu"><div class="menu-items"><ul><li class="first-item">Menu Item 1</li><li>Menu Item 2</li><li>Menu Item 3</li><li>Menu Item 4</li><li>Menu Item 5</li><li>Menu Item 6</li><li>Menu Item 7</li><li>Menu Item 8</li><li>Menu Item 9</li><li>Menu Item 10</li></ul></div></div>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-items">
      <ul>
        <li class="first-item">Menu Item 1</li>
        <li>Menu Item 2</li>
        <li>Menu Item 3</li>
        <li>Menu Item 4</li>
        <li>Menu Item 5</li>
        <li>Menu Item 6</li>
        <li>Menu Item 7</li>
        <li>Menu Item 8</li>
        <li>Menu Item 9</li>
        <li>Menu Item 10</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If this doesn't work for you, please reply to me in the comments because your explanation isn't clear...

Comment: There is no change adding a <br> tag.

Comment: I don't really understand your explanation of what you want.